# How to open current TextMate file in another application

Tags: emacs, textmate, aquamacs

I'm basically using TextMate only for its project drawer, find in project, and AckMate. What I'd like to do is automatically open the current file in another application (Aquamacs to be specific).

Is there a keyboard shotcut to open the current file in another/default application?
Or perhaps run some arbitrary shell script based on the current file?
Or at least copy the file path to clipboard?

If I could get the same functionality of these TextMate things (with the same usability and prettiness) in Aquamacs of course that'd be great too, but in my experience the TextMate tools are superior.

Comment: I got the copy file path to clipboard part: http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/27/textmate-tip-where-am-i

Comment: solved my own problem... edited the bundle command to do this `echo -n "$TM_FILEPATH" | xargs aquamacs`

Comment: You can answer your question yourself, using the appropriate button below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an AppleScript solution that opens the current file in another application, but isn't limited to command line applications, but rather GUI ones:

- Go to *Bundles » Bundle Editor » Show Bundle Editor* (or press *⌃ ⌥ ⌘ B*).
- Create a new bundle if you like, and add a new command (1). Then, give it a name you like (2).

  [image]
- Copy and paste the following (3). I did this for TextEdit, but most other applications should work.

  ```
  open "$TM_FILEPATH" -a TextEdit
  ```

  **Note:** Aquamacs doesn't work with this, but you've found a workaround. With Aquamacs, it's enough to paste `aquamacs "$TM_FILEPATH"` instead of the `open` command.
- Make sure to set *Input* to "None" and *Output* to "Discard".
- Create an optional keyboard shortcut for it.
- Close the bundle editor. Now you can call your new bundle command over *Bundles » Your Bundle Name » Your Command Name* or the shortcut you've set up.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to immediately execute a command once the application opens? Specifically I want to press "alt g g $TM_LINE_NUMBER" as soon as Aquamacs has opened up, in order to jump to that line number.

Comment: @mark Just look at [the answer I posted on your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/345936/aquamacs-open-and-jump-to-line-number/345954#345954)! You can use AppleScript for that. Worked for me.

Comment: `$TM_FILEPATH` isn't expanded inside single quotes. You could just use `open "$TM_FILEPATH" -a TextEdit` instead.